# AngularJs $http post on page load

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

my page is display users from database. when form submit i can display $http.post data. But page loaded nothing is displayed. How i can display my $http.post data page loaded(sorry everyone my english very bad)

This is my view.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src='angular.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myapp', [])
                    .controller('mycon', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

                            var update = function() {
                                $http.post('query.php').success(function(data, status) {
                                    return data;
                                });
                            };

                            $scope.send = function() {
                                var data = JSON.stringify($scope.user);

                                $http.post('query.php', data).success(function(data, status) {
                                    $scope.da = data;
                                    $scope.angularList = data; // or update();
                                });
                            };
                            $scope.angularList = update();

                        }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mycon">

        <ul ng-repeat="mylist in angularList">
            <li>{{mylist.name}}</li>
            <li>{{mylist.password}}</li>
            <li>{{mylist.role}}</li>
        </ul>

        <h1> Add new user:</h1>
        <form ng-submit="send()">
            Name:   <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/> 
            Login:  <input type="text" ng-model="user.pass"/>

            <select  ng-model="user.role">
                <option>user</option>
                <option>admin</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit"  value="Add"/>
        </form>
        data: {{da}}<br>
        status: {{st}}
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my query.php

```
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('phpang');


if(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))){
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$fn=$data->name;
$ln=$data->pass;
$rl=$data->role;                                                                                                                         

$query_ins='insert into users (name,password,role) values("'.$fn.'","'.$ln.'","'.$rl.'")';
mysql_query($query_ins);
}
$query='select * from users'; 
$select=mysql_query($query);
$myphplist=[];
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $myphplist[]=$row;
}

$myJson=json_encode($myphplist);

echo $myJson;
```

Comment: where is 'mylist' in your code?

Comment: myList is array and equals $myJson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http` makes async calls, so you should use callbacks or something.

```
                        var update = function(callback) {
                            $http.get('query.php').success(function(data, status) {
                                callback(data);
                            });
                        };

                        $scope.send = function() {
                            var data = JSON.stringify($scope.user);

                            $http.post('query.php', data).success(function(data, status) {
                                $scope.da = data;
                                $scope.angularList = data; // or update();
                            });
                        };

                        update(function(data){
                            $scope.angularList = data;
                        });
```

Some tips:

You don't need to do `JSON.stringify($scope.user)`, you can pass your object, like `$http.post('query.php', $scope.user)`

Use `GET` instead of `POST` in this case. Use `POST` only if it makes some changes to your data.

Comment: do you see my example? I made it for you. Try it out, it should work. It is callback version of your code

Comment: I think because `$http.post()` requires some data. I have changed to `$http.get()` in your `update` function. Try it out.